# Posting content editable div value

Tags: jquery, post

I need to create a customized textbox and I couldn't do it with `<input type="text" />` because of its limitations. I want to create my own textbox using jQuery. But now I'm concerned about posting its data. I have thought of these two options:

1. `<div data-name="element-name" class="textbox">`
   this way using `$('.textbox').textBox()` will create hidden inputs with `name` that is given for the div as `data-name` and editing div content will alter the input value and I don't need further posting issues.
2. posting values with `$.post()` method.

Before I start I wanted to know if either of these ways could be problematic later. Any suggestions? other options?

Comment: What input field limitations are keeping you from using the input tag?

Comment: I'm interested to know what limitations stopped you using normal inputs? As long as you `encodeURIComponent(data)` with `$.post` or `serialize` you should be fine for that method

Comment: for example placeholder property doesn't work in lower versions of IE.  highlighting. adding link to a part of a text (keep in mind that my plugin will also be used as textarea)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what the world would be like if we didn't have to support outdated browsers…

Comment: @Luxelin whenever I'm writing a code I'm always worried will it work in IE? or should I write a patch for it ;)

Comment: Internet Explorer just needs to go off to a faraway corner, curl up into a fetal position, and die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is essentially the same method used by TinyMCE's inline editing option:
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php

So that option is probably your best bet.  You could also just use TinyMCE or CKEditor, if having a full-featured wysiwyg is appealing.

Comment: I looked for some editors some are great but huge in size (our country internet speed is low) some has extra options I don't need. some don't have some options I need.... so I thought best bet is to create my own editor that would function exactly as I need.

Comment: I hear you, and building your own wysiwyg has become a lot easier as most browsers now support contenteditable.  But as someone who maintained a substandard wysiwyg editor for years I can tell you that wysiwyg is hard and the established editors have solved some pretty tricky cross-browser problems.  The latest TinyMCE is pretty small too, and you can write your own plugins for it if you want.

Comment: its compressed version is 275 KB. It doesn't have highlighting (the most important feature I need). also it really looks nice

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by highlighting?  You can set up custom formats to apply a background color to text, if that's what you're looking for.  If the download size is a dealbreaker, then it's a dealbreaker.  Just a warning that you may be in for more work than you bargained for, especially if your needs expand.

Comment: nothing..... Its greaaaaaat. It even support languages and direction.  Thanks a lot ...I just have to change some css codes to match my page... Thanks again